# Is there a function that is not absolutely integrable in [−π,π] so that its Fourier Series Exists?

Tags: fourier-analysis

For existence of Fourier coefficients of a function f is sufficient that f is absolutely integrable in [−π,π] but, is this condition necessary? that is, is there a function that is not absolutely integrable in [−π,π] so that its Fourier series Exists?
Consider the usual trigonometric system.

Comment: How do you define $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx$, if $\int |f|dx = \infty$? More concrete: What is then its Fourier Series?

Comment: This is the problem, because if $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|dx$ converges then Fourier Series of $f$ exists always , but is possible that is there a functión that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|dx$ diverges (no necessarily $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)dx$ diverges) and its Fourier series exists?
if it is not possible why?

Comment: If $\int |f|d\mu = \infty$, then always $\int fd\mu = \pm \infty$ (if either $\int f^+d\mu < \infty$ or $\int f^-d\mu < \infty$) or this integral does not exist.

Comment: I consider that this is false, because $\int_{a}^{\infty} \dfrac{sin(x)}{x}dx$ converges $\forall a>0$ but $\int_{a}^{\infty} \dfrac{|sin(x)|}{x} dx$ diverges

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona yes, I know. In this theory all is very nice because $\mathcal{L}_2$ is a Hilbert space. However, Serie Fourier also can be defined for another type of function (Function $f$ such that $f \notin \mathcal{L_2}$), and in these cases is this problem.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question unless you supply a precise definition of what you mean by saying "the Fourier series exists". Given a function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, how do you propose to define its Fourier coefficients? And assuming you can define each individual Fourier coefficient, what do you mean by a series "existing"? Do you require the series to converge in some way? If not, then aren't you just asking if each Fourier coefficient exists?

Comment: The question has also been posted on MathStackExchange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730663/is-there-a-function-that-is-not-absolutely-integrable-in-pi-pi-so-that-it which I think is a more appropriate place for it

Answer (score 3):

All $2π$ periodic distributions are temperate and since all temperate distributions have a Fourier transform, you have plenty of examples. Note that the previous statements prove the power of abstract nonsense in Mathematics: you define for $u\in \mathscr S(\mathbb R)$ the Fourier transform
$$
\hat u(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-2iπ x \xi } u(x) dx,
$$
and you can prove that it is an isomorphism of $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$, with the inverse given by
$
u(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} e^{2iπ x \xi } \hat u(\xi) d\xi.
$
Well, not trivial but very standard with direct proofs. Then you dramatically increase the generality by defining the Fourier transform of a temperate distribution $T$, as
$$
\langle \hat T,\phi\rangle_{\mathscr S'(\mathbb R),\mathscr S(\mathbb R)}
=\langle T,\hat \phi\rangle_{\mathscr S'(\mathbb R),\mathscr S(\mathbb R)},
$$
and with $\mathcal F$ standing for the Fourier transform and $\mathcal C$ for the mapping $T(x)\mapsto T(-x)$ (clearly defined for a function and also by duality for distributions). Then (and this is the power referred to above), you get trivially that for any tempered distribution $T$
$$
\mathcal C\mathcal F \mathcal F T=T.
$$
For instance you get with $H=\mathbf 1_{\mathbb R_+}$,
$
\hat H=\frac12\delta_0+\frac{1}{2π i}\textrm{pv}\frac1x.
$

Comment: Yes, of course you can extend the domain of definition and get the above mentioned results. But I think a beginner (?) is misguided by not answering the original question.

Comment: The OP is working on the torus $[-\pi,\pi]$, not on the whole real line.

Comment: @PhoemueX Periodic functions are defined everywhere and a classical way to obtain the classical expansion in Fourier series for a periodic distribution is to use the Fourier inversion formula above on the real line.

Comment: @Dieter Kadelka I tried to answer the question which was "Can we define the Fourier transform on a larger set than $L^1$?". The distributional framework with temperate distribution is providing a very large space on which the Fourier transform makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about $1/x$, for distributional Fourier transform